# use proc shorthand with argument

Tags: ruby

is there a way to the ampersand syntax shortcut for block arguments, with a normal argument as well? a specific example:

```
def ewa_test(x, o)
  if o.include? x
    o << "more #{x}"
  else
    o << x
  end
end

fridge_contents = %w( pepperoni green_onions mushrooms olives chives )

# shortcut for calling upcase on every element
# returns ["PEPPERONI", "GREEN_ONIONS", "MUSHROOMS", "OLIVES", "CHIVES"]
fridge_contents.map(&:upcase)

# same shortcut to call ewa_test on every element
fridge_contents.each_with_object([]) { |x, o| ewa_test(x, o) }

# obviously without an object argument, each_with_object raises ArgumentError
fridge_contents.each_with_object(&:ewa_test)

# each raises NoMethodError: private method `ewa_test' called for "pepperoni":String
fridge_contents.each_with_object([], &:ewa_test)

# syntax error
fridge_contents.each_with_object(&:ewa_test, [])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track here, but remember that the `&:x` notation means something specific to iterators like `map`:

```
a.map(&:x)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a.map { |o| o.send(:x) }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
a.map { |o| o.x }
```

There's no provision for supplying multiple arguments. In your case you need to do this:

```
fridge_contents.each_with_object([], &method(:ewa_test))
```

Where `method(:x)` returns a way of calling an arbitrary method that's not object-specific.

Comment: from reading the docs, it seems like Method#to_proc and Symbol#to_proc should have the same result, but it looks like the Symbol version returns a lambda. I tried and failed to fully understand this answer but it was worth the effort.